How to handle DayOfWeek field in a database when users from different time zones query the data?
I have a table in my database where one of the columns represents the DayOfWeek. This column stores information about recurring sessions that occur on specific days (e.g., Monday, Tuesday). The Session table includes startTime and endTime columns (both defined as Time), which represent the specific times for these sessions on the corresponding DayOfWeek in the group.
The Challenge:
Users from different time zones might see incorrect DayOfWeek values when crossing over into the next or previous day due to time zone differences. Since the DayOfWeek is stored based on UTC, it could shift to the wrong day for some users, making it appear that the session is scheduled for a different day than intended.
For example, let’s say a admin wants to create a group for Monday. The admin selects Monday on the client-side (e.g., 2020/08/08 00:00 in their local time). This date is then converted to UTC, and assuming a time zone offset of 3 hours, it becomes:
2020/08/07 21:00 (Sunday)

So, when this date is sent to the server, it records Sunday instead of Monday, and a record is added to the Group table for Sunday instead of the intended Monday.
The dates in this example are hypothetical, but this issue illustrates the problem with handling DayOfWeek across different time zones.
I understand that:
If I use DayOfWeek, the ActiveDate column will not be utilized, and vice versa.
I need to handle this dynamically to ensure that users across different time zones see the correct day and time for their sessions.
My Current Table Structure:
public class Group : BaseEntity
{
    public DayOfWeek? DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActiveDate { get; set; }
    public bool ForActiveDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupSession> GroupSessions { get; set; }
}

public class Session : BaseEntity
{
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; } // 03:30 - ...
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; } // ... - 05:00
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<GroupSession> GroupSessions { get; set; }
}

Any advice, examples, or best practices for how to handle this would be greatly appreciated!

And what is the relation now between dayofweek and the stored date?

Thank you for your question! I updated the body of the question.

You cannot. Or put differently: There is no way to say "Monday at 3 o'clock", so it will point to the same instant in time for all time zones. You would have to add the timezone in resp. for which it had been configured. If on the other hand "Monday at 3 o'clock" is supposed to mean exactly that just for each time zone locally, then it is correct already. It will just refer to 24 different instants in time (potentially).

Thank you for your insights! I understand that "Monday at 3 o'clock" would indeed refer to different moments in time across various time zones.
To clarify, my Session table includes startTime and endTime fields, both of type Time, which represent the specific times for sessions on the corresponding DayOfWeek in the Group. The idea is to have recurring sessions at the same local time, regardless of the time zone.
Given this, I want to ensure that when users query for sessions, they see the correct DayOfWeek and associated time based on their local time zone.

Ok, let's recap: "Monday, 3:00" would refer to local 3:00 which you would persist as "Monday, 3:00Z" or "Monday, 01:00Z" (given a local timezone with Z+2:00) ? And to make things simpler: Have you been considering Daylight savings?

Can you even guarantee that start and endtime will be on the same day? I only understand half of what you are trying here but it sounds problematic in multiple aspects. When its some sort of session data for a certain timezone then store it for that timezone and not in Utc?

Thank you both for your insightful comments!
I agree that "Monday, 3:00" should refer to the local time and should be stored with respect to the corresponding timezone. I am considering how to handle Daylight Saving Time changes to ensure that sessions are accurate throughout the year.
it is indeed possible for startTime and endTime to fall on different days, especially if a session lasts overnight. I'm evaluating whether it might be more appropriate to store session data in local time to minimize confusion for users.

Handling time accross different timezones may be a difficult task. Aside from the technical issues, you first of all have to be clear about what something like "Monday 3:00 PM" even means with respect to different timezones. Especially if users from different timezones look at the very same record in your database. This may depend on the usecase, but actually the only person who can answer this you. Until this point isn't clarified, there is no point in talking about technical details.

Thank you for your comment!
To clarify, in my design, we either use DayOfWeek for recurring sessions or ActiveDate for specific one-off sessions. If we choose to use DayOfWeek, the ActiveDate field will not be utilized, and vice versa.
I understand that the interpretation of "Monday 3:00" may vary depending on users' time zones, and I’m working to ensure that the displayed information is accurate for each user. Your insights are valuable as I navigate these complexities!

I recommend you read NodaTime's overview and code concepts, even if you don't use NodaTime, it might help you clarify some concepts - like the difference between instant, utc, local time and zoned time.

Thank you for the recommendation! I'll definitely check it out!

Can you capture the Client Date Time with Offset?

You change users' "local" queries to UTC time; and query the data using UTC date functions; then return the results with UTC times converted to local times.

I think it's not a good solution, I tried several methods, now I'm editing the question body

@Showechy Please provide the database table structure you have, including the column types. Then add example data what is stored in these tables. After that describe how different users from different timezones should see/read these values and/or what should happen with these time values. It is unclear if you want to reference a specific point in time or just a "loose" description like "Monday 3:00 AM".

thanks for your comment! sure I will update the question body.
